# Density of Domain of Laplacian Operator in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{N})$

Tags: lp-spaces, laplacian, semigroup-of-operators

Let $B : H^1(\mathbb{R}^{N})\to H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a linear operator defined as follows
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
D(B) := \{\varphi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\, | \, \Delta\varphi\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N) \}\\
\forall\varphi\in D(B), B\varphi=\Delta\varphi
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, we know that $B$ is a dense and maximal dissipative operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ which generates a contraction semigroup $(S(t))_{t\geq0}$

Now, my question is as follows
Assume that $C: L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N})\to L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$. How do I define $D(C)$ so that $D(C)$ is dense in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$? I don't think I can apply the technique in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ because it does not have a Hilbert Space structure.

I need $C$ to be a maximal dissipative operator with dense domain in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ in order to use Hille-Yoshida Theorem so that I can apply it to obtain a local existence result.

Any help or hint or even good reference will be appreciated. I currently use "Introduction to Semilinear Evolution Equations" by Cazenave and Haraux.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Terribly late to the part, but still 2 comments: 1) Your operator $B$ is not maximally dissipative in $L^2$. You should require $\Delta\phi\in L^2$ instead to make it maximally dissipative. 2) Of course it depends on the operator $C$ you want to define. I assume you want to define the Laplacian on $L^\infty$. In this case it is not reasonable to assume that it would be maximally dissipative. Indeed, if you define the heat semigroup on $L^\infty$ by the usual convolution formula, then it is not strongly continuous.